# Active menu trail for multiple menu item with the same path

Tags: hooks

It is possible to have menu items that point to the same node and have the active state dynamic?

If I click the link 'List item A1' I would like to become active the link 'List item A'.

If I click the link 'List item B1' I would like to become active the link 'List item B'.

```
 - List item A (node/1)
 --  List item A1 (node/2)

 - List item B (node/3)
 --  List item B1 (node/2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [module menu-position](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_position) for this. When you add a new rule, just choose the option *Mark the rule's parent menu item as being "active"* on the settings page. You probably have to create a css rule for your theme, too.

Comment: I do not think to solve with this module, I tried.
The problem is that with two menu items to the same node, Drupal adds active state just a one item

Comment: I misread your question, sorry. You can definitely try https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_node_menu and https://www.drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks